# Problems with gxp Print plugin via opengeosuite sdk

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, web-mapping, boundless-suite, sdk

I am trying to import the print plugin within an application built using the Opengeo Suite sdk and I have run into issues as is described in the following thread
https://getsatisfaction.com/opengeo/topics/doubts_about_the_use_of_print_from_openlayers_ready_gxp

After having followed all the instructions provided, I still cannot get the print plugin the work. The print button appears but I get the message

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function 

This seems to be on the following line: 
var scaleLine = new OpenLayers.Control.ScaleLine({ ...
```

I have also tried using an alternate approach wherein I have a handler for the print button as is shown below:

```
    var app = new gxp.Viewer({
    portalConfig: {
        layout: "border",
        region: "center",
    ...
    ...
    ...
    // layer sources
    sources: {
        local: {
            ptype: "gxp_wmscsource",
            url: "/geoserver/wms",
            version: "1.1.1"
        },
        osm: {
            ptype: "gxp_osmsource"
        },
        geonetwork: {
            ptype: "gxp_cataloguesource",
            url: "/geonetwork/srv/en/csw",
            title: "Geonetwork"
        },
        ol: {
            ptype: "gxp_olsource"
        }
    },

    // map and layers
    map: {
        id: "mymap", // id needed to reference map in portalConfig above
        title: "Map",
        //projection: "EPSG:900913",
        //center: [-10764594.758211, 4523072.3184791],
        projection: "EPSG:4326",
        center: [-97, 38],
        zoom: 3,
        layers: [{
            source: "ol",
            type: "OpenLayers.Layer.WMS",
            args: ["World map", "http://vmap0.tiles.osgeo.org/wms/vmap0", {layers: 'basic'}],
            group: "background"
        }, {
            source: "ol",
            type: "OpenLayers.Layer",
            args: ["Blank"],
            visibility: false,
            group: "background"

            //source: "osm",
            //name: "mapnik",
            //group: "background"
        }//, {
            //source: "local",
            //name: "usa:states",
            //selected: true
        //}//, {
            //source: "google",
            //name: "ROADMAP",
            //group: "background"
        //}
        ],
        bbar: [{
            text: "Print...",
            handler: showPrintWindow
        }],
        items: [{
            xtype: "gx_zoomslider",
            vertical: true,
            height: 100
        }]
    }

});

function showPrintWindow() {
    var printWindow = new Ext.Window({
        title: "Print",
        modal: true,
        border: false,
        resizable: false,
        width: 360,
        autoHeight: true,
        items: new GeoExt.ux.PrintPreview({
            autoHeight: true,
            printMapPanel: {
                // limit scales to those that can be previewed
                limitScales: true,
                // no zooming on the map
                map: {controls: [
                    new OpenLayers.Control.Navigation({
                        zoomBoxEnabled: false,
                        zoomWheelEnabled: false
                    }),
                    new OpenLayers.Control.PanPanel()
                ]}
            },
            printProvider: {
                // using get for remote service access without same origin
                // restriction. For async requests, we would set method to "POST".
                method: "GET",
                //method: "POST",

                // capabilities from script tag in Printing.html.
                capabilities: printCapabilities,
                listeners: {
                    "print": function() {printWindow.close();}
                }
            },
            includeLegend: true,
            mapTitle: "PrintMapPanel Demo",
            sourceMap: app.map
        })
    }).show().center();
}
```

From within the showPrintWindow function the sourceMap is set to app.map. However, when I click on the print button now, I get the error message:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object #<Object> has no method 'getProjection' PrintMapPanel.js:176
GeoExt.PrintMapPanel.Ext.extend.initComponent PrintMapPanel.js:176
Ext.Component ext-all.js:7
L ext-base.js:7
L ext-base.js:7
L ext-base.js:7
L ext-base.js:7
L ext-base.js:7
GeoExt.ux.PrintPreview.Ext.extend.initComponent PrintPreview.js:156
Ext.Component ext-all.js:7
L ext-base.js:7
L ext-base.js:7
L ext-base.js:7
showPrintWindow app.js:185
Ext.Button.Ext.extend.onClick ext-all.js:7
I
```

I am not entirely sure how I can get this working and any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. In the app.js:

include at the beginning:

```
 * @require plugins/Print.js
 * @require GeoExt.ux/PrintPreview.js
 * @require GeoExt/widgets/PrintMapPanel.js
 * @require GeoExt/plugins/PrintProviderField.js
 * @require GeoExt/plugins/PrintPageField.js
 * @require OpenLayers/Control/ScaleLine.js
```

under the tools section also insert:

```
    {
   ptype: "gxp_print",
   customParams: {outputFilename: 'GeoExplorer-print'},
   printService: "/geoserver/pdf/",
   actionTarget: "map.tbar",
   showButtonText: true
}
```

1. Download and extract from [github the printpreview.css](https://github.com/opengeo/PrintPreview/tree/master/resources/css), [GeoExt.ux](https://github.com/opengeo/PrintPreview/tree/master/lib) etc. as outlined [here](https://getsatisfaction.com/opengeo/topics/doubts_about_the_use_of_print_from_openlayers_ready_gxp):
2. Embed the css into the index.html

`<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="src/geoext/resources/css/printpreview.css">`

That's it. I followed these steps and it worked. (Suite 3.0.1),
All the best!

Comment: :( there are changes in opengeo suite 4.6. does any have new example ?