# Suite SDK gxp Print plugin

Tags: openlayers-2, javascript, geoext, boundless-suite, sdk

I have problem with gxp print plugin.
I create new sdk project `suite-sdk create ~/sdk`. Next I do everything from [Problems with gxp Print plugin via opengeosuite sdk](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44222/problems-with-gxp-print-plugin-via-opengeosuite-sdk) but there is another problem.
But I don't know where. After I click on the print button in print preview modal nothing happens.
Here is a screen shot from firebug [JPG](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzN7M.jpg)

Anyone know how to fix that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your screenshot shows an OPTIONS request. I assume that your print service is not at the same origin as your application, and your print service does not send CORS headers. You will have to use the GET method to talk to the print service (see http://geoext.org/lib/GeoExt/data/PrintProvider.html for details). This option is not supported in the SDK, but you can add the following as first line of code in your application to change the default:

```
GeoExt.data.PrintProvider.prototype.method = 'GET';
```

Note that you will also have to add a script tag to the app resources of your index.html:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://path.to/geoserver/pdf/info.json?var=printCapabilities"></script>
```