# Opengeo suite 4.6, gxp template, problem in adding print tool

Tags: javascript, boundless-suite, openlayers-2, gxp

I have checked this question [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/44222/problems-with-gxp-print-plugin-via-opengeosuite-sdk)  but it one of the link is missing and it was on suite 3.0  and i have no idea if it will work on suite 4.6.I have installed the print extension in opengeosuite then checked the default link "http://localhost:8080/geoserver/pdf/info.json?var=printCapabilities" 
print capabilities its working   here is my code for app.js

```
/**
 * Add all your dependencies here.
 * @require plugins/Print.js
 * @require GeoExt.ux/PrintPreview.js
 * @require GeoExt/plugins/PrintProviderField.js
 * @require GeoExt/plugins/PrintPageField.js
 * @require OpenLayers/Control/ScaleLine.js
 * @require widgets/Viewer.js
 * @require plugins/LayerTree.js
 * @require plugins/OLSource.js
 * @require plugins/OSMSource.js
 * @require plugins/WMSCSource.js
 * @require plugins/ZoomToExtent.js
 * @require plugins/NavigationHistory.js
 * @require plugins/Zoom.js
 * @require plugins/AddLayers.js
 * @require plugins/RemoveLayer.js
 * @require RowExpander.js
 * @require GeoExt/widgets/PrintMapPanel.js
*/
```

added ptype in tools section of the app.js

```
{
    ptype: "gxp_print",
    customParams: {outputFilename: 'GeoExplorer-print'},
    printService: "/geoserver/pdf/",
    actionTarget: "map.tbar",
    showButtonText: true
}
```

added the css, GeoExt.ux.
Have a look at the screen shot of error 
[image]

If there some tutorial for it let me know.

Comment: It seems your build might miss OpenLayers.Layer.Vector since line 197 points to that, so try adding a requires for that: https://github.com/geoext/geoext/blob/cb6f51a79e22b7b5b698f23e1d86254bb35ddf18/lib/GeoExt/widgets/PrintMapPanel.js#L197